# Defining with docstrings in yaml file: Parsing errors

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I am trying to parse the following yaml file:

```
\- api:

  api_first: """this is some docstring """
```

I basically want to use the triple quotes and have some statements within them.
But when I use the yaml library it throws some errors for me

```
In [1]: import yaml

In [2]:with open('new.yaml') as f:
...:     dataMap = yaml.safe_load(f)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-2266b3e8606a> in <module>()
  1
  2 with open('new.yaml') as f:
  ----> 3     dataMap = yaml.safe_load(f)
/phaedrus/home/skorada/lib/python3.5/site-
 packages/yaml/parser.py in parse_block_sequence_entry(self)
391             token = self.peek_token()
392             raise ParserError("while parsing a block collection", 
self.marks[-1],
--> 393                     "expected <block end>, but found %r" % token.id, 
token.start_mark)
394         token = self.get_token()
395         event = SequenceEndEvent(token.start_mark, token.end_mark)

ParserError: while parsing a block collection
in "new.yaml", line 1, column 1
expected <block end>, but found '?'
in "new.yaml", line 2, column 1
```

Really not sure what the issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no triple quotes in YAML. Your scalar can be single quoted, double quoted, non-quoted, or (in block-style) literal or folding.

If you want to emulate Python's triple-quoted strings and you don't have any control characters that need escaping (those do not include the newline character) you can use block style literal scalars:

```
api:

  api_first: |
     this is some docstring 
     with newlines after each line
```

. If you have control characters, you have to use double quoted scalars in YAML and either have newlines as `\n` or as double newlines within the double quotes.

Your `"""this is some docstring """` gets interpreted as three scalars on one line (`""`, `"this is some docstring "`, and `""`) and that is not valid YAML.

I assume the starting `\` in your YAML is a typo.

Comment: Hi Anthon,   Thanks for replying. I think i was trying a multi-line. This can be solved by using "|" and it worked for me.

Comment: That is the `block style literal scalar` I indicated in my answer. I should have included an example.